# Generic Int conversion to scalar

Tags: scala, converting, generics, meta-programming

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to write a generic function to convert from `Int` to any scalar.

For example:

```
val res: Float = convertInt[Float](12)
val res: Double = convertInt[Double](12)
//etc
```

I've achieved the following code:

```
  trait FromIntConverter[T]{
    def apply(int: Int): T
  }

  def convertInt[T](int: Int)(implicit converter: FromIntConverter[T]): T = converter(int)

  implicit val IntToIntConverter = new FromIntConverter[Int]{
    def apply(int: Int) = int
  }

  implicit val IntToFloatConverter = new FromIntConverter[Float]{
    def apply(int: Int) = int.toFloat
  }

  implicit val IntToDoubleConverter = new FromIntConverter[Double]{
    def apply(int: Int) = int.toDouble
  }
  //etc
```

Is it ok in regards to readability/brevity/performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok in regards of readability, but it can be shortened.

There is no need to create a dedicated `trait FromIntConverter` with implementations. All that can happen anonymously.

The `convertInt` function can take a function as implicit parameter:

```
def convertInt[T](i: Int)(implicit converter: Int => T) = converter.apply(i)
```

And all the implicit `val`s can become one-liners:

```
implicit def intToFloat(i: Int) = i.toFloat

implicit def intToDouble(i: Int) = i.toDouble
```

P.S. I discourage the use of `int` as variable name, that shouldn't collide with the Java type name.